# Do I need to define sharing for test classes?

Tags: apex, security-review

The question is simple: should **test classes** be defined with sharing `with sharing | without sharing | inherited sharing` to pass the security review?

Technically Salesforce enforces this by saying it in their [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.secure_coding_guide.meta/secure_coding_guide/secure_coding_lightning_security.htm):

> Mark all (non-interface) classes as either with sharing, without
>   sharing, or inherited sharing.

Yet it seems redundant for test classes. If it really needs to be, then why?

Answer (score 1):

Test classes does not have concept of sharing because you would never use test class to get/post/delete/other DML/queries in test class/methods.

But, you would use test classes and its methods to check whether record accessibility for view/read/delete is as per business specifications in given Apex classes

Comment: I don't think I agree here. Test class behavior can definitely change based on whether or not the class is declared `with sharing`.

Comment: So does the security review team require test classes to be declared with sharing specification?